# place javascript variables in html - several ways, which one to choose?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm on some html where i have to place some variables in depency of language choosen by user. For several reasons I am only able to do this client-side.

I have figured out different ways to do so, now I'm asking myself which is the best way to do this (best way in this case means "fastest", "most fail-safe" and so on).

The variables are stored in a json-file looking like this:

```
lang = {
"nav" : {
    "categories" : {
        "header" : {
            "de" : "Kategorien",
            "en" : "Categories"
        },
    },
    "search" : {
        "placeholder" : {
            "de" : "Suchen nach...",
            "en" : "search for..."
        },
        "button" : {
            "de" : "Finden",
            "en" : "Find"
        },
    },
},
"benefits" : {
    "first" : {
        "title" : {
            "de" : "irgendwas",
            "en" : "something"
        },
        "content" : {
            "de" : "blablabla",
            "en" : "blablabla in english"
        },
    },
    "second" : {
        "title" : {
            "de" : "irgendwas anderes",
            "en" : "something else"
        },
        "content" : {
            "de" : "noch mehr blablabla",
            "en" : "some more blablabla in english"
        },
    },
},
}
```

now i could place the variables directly using little script everywhere they shall be, for example:

```
<script>document.write(lang.nav.search.button[language])</script>
```

On the other side instead of the script i could place a

```
<span id="lang.nav.search.button"></span>
```

or any other tag and have an external javascript where i replace/append/prepend or whatever.

To make it a bit more complicated, in some cases i have to set attributes of elements in dependency of the choosen language, and because direct execution of the script above inside another tag to set attribute isn't possible **(or is there some way to do so?)** i use a function to get the parent Element of the current position in the DOM

```
function scriptparent() {
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  return scripts[scripts.length - 1].parentNode;
};
```

and set the attribute like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <script>scriptparent().firstElementChild.placeholder = lang.nav.search.placeholder[language];</script>
</div>
```

When finished my project there will be something between 50 - 100 variables, so, any suggestion which way to prefer? Or maybe someone has an even better way to deal with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into using a template engine like [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/) for example.

Comment: There's countless libraries out there for this, pick one.

Comment: For example Handlebars JS and here is an example http://blog.edouard-lopez.com/how-to-localize-content-with-handlebarsjs/

Comment: Note, this is to be used for an eBay listing template, it runs inside an iframe on eBay. 

**That means I'm heavily restricted on javascript usage**

Although i know how to implement some scripts and how to get data from anywhere on the web into that iframe, but I have to check out if there is a way to use a templating engine in this case.

I'm also a bit courious if it's really neccesary, because i just want to localize it, and using the 2 ways mentioned above will work like a charm.

The question is just which way is "better" one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://i18next.com/ library for translations. Use it together with a template library, mustache, handlebars or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://angular-translate.github.io/ library for translations. This solution is the 1st use by the generator of application. I use JHipster application with this library. Usage and performance is good.